# How can I calculate a transformation so that two reference points in two images are matching?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have a blue input image (figure 1) with known width and height and known points A and B. I have a second red input image (figure 2) with known points A and B, which is the base image. The goal is to overlay the blue image over the red base image so that the points A and B are superimposed each (figure 4). It can only be done by providing the upper right (P1) and lower left (P2) coordinates for the blue image in the coordinate system of the red image (intermediate figure 3) and then by rotating the blue image around its center by a certain angle (alpha).

How can I calculate P1, P2 and alpha?

Comment: Is the distance between $A$ and $B$ always the same, or might you also need to scale?

Comment: @aschepler Unfortunately not, I also need to scale

Comment: Shall we assume that the scaling factor is the same in both dimensions?

Comment: @Saeed Yes, I forgot to mention that. Scaling on the blue image can only be done by the same factor in both dimensions.

Comment: If you [use complex numbers to represent the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane), then your desired transformation is of the form $z\mapsto az+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are unknown complex constants, and your two pairs of points give a system of two linear equations, which are easy to solve.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the figure you provide, you want to transform the blue image to match the red image.  *Let the two images initially share a common origin, say the top left corner of each image, and also their edges aligned*.  Let the $x$ axis point to the right of the images, and the $y$ axis point downward.  Using a ruler you can find the coordinates in $(x,y)$ for the red picture and the blue picture.  The points are $A_r,B_r$ on the red image and correspondingly $A_b$ and $B_b$ on the blue image.

Let the center of the blue rectangle be at $C = (x_b, y_b)$

First we want to shift the blue image by an unknown displacement V,
The new coordinates are

$C' = C + V$

$A_b' = A_b + V$

$B_b' = B_b + V$

Now, we want to find $V$ such that when rotating $A_b'$ and $B_b'$ about $C'$ they match with $A_r$, $B_r$.

This means we want

$A_r = C' + R (A_b' - C') $

$B_r = C' + R (B_b'- C' ) $

for some $2 \times 2 $ rotation matrix $R$.

Substituting $A_b', B_b', C'$:

$A_r = C' + R (A_b - C) $

$ B_r = C' + R (B_b - C)$

Subtract you get,

$A_r - B_r = R (A_b - B_b)$

To find the angle of rotation: if the phase angle of $(A_r-B_r)$ is $\phi_1$ and that of $(A_b - B_p)$ is $\phi_2$ , then the angle of rotation is  $\alpha = \phi_1 - \phi_2$.  Now we can compute $R$ as follows:

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \alpha && - \sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha && \cos \alpha \end{bmatrix} $

Then, we have

$C' = A_r - R (A_b - C) $

And the shift $V$ is

$V =(V_x, V_y) = C' - C = A_r - R(A_b - C) - C $

Initially the shown corners of the blue image are at $(W, 0)$ and $(0, H)$ , so they become at

$P_1 = (W + V_x , V_y)  $ and $P_2 =  (V_x, H + V_y) $

Comment: Thank you very much! Even though I think you are not taking into account that $\frac{|AB_{r}|}{|AB_{b}|} \ne 1$ you explanation has led me to a working solution that solves the problem. There are a few minor typos I think: defined $C_b$ but then just used $C$ and further down it should be $(A_b - B_b)$ instead of $(Ab - Ap)$.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll correct the typos shortly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define points $P1$ and $P2$ as simple linear functions of $A_{blue}$ and **i** and **j**, unit vectors along width and hight of the blue image
2. Calculate $scaleFactor = \frac{|AB_{red}|}{|AB_{blue}|}$
3. Calculate $\alpha = arctan(slope(AB_{red})) - arctan(slope(AB_{blue}))$
4. Scale **i** and **j** by scaleFactor
5. Rotate new **i** and **j** by $\alpha$
6. Insert $A_{red}$, transformed **i**, transformed **j** in the functions of step 1 to calculate the transformed $P1$ and $P2$.

Comment: Could you please explain step 1 a bit more in detail? I've implemented 2 and 3 and that is working so far but I don't understand how to calculate $P1$ and $P2$ from $A_{blue}$ and $\textbf{i}$ and $\textbf{j}$. Could you maybe provide a little example for that?

Comment: For example, if in the initial blue image the position of $P1$ with respect to $A_{blue}$ is $(-3,-4)$ , define: 
$P1 = f1(A,i,j) = A -3i - 4j$

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been really helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This can be formulated in a 2D Cartesian coordinates system where the $y$ axis points downward.

But I prefer not to give a full solution.

Assuming that:

1. **both images are rectangles**;
2. **both images initially have their sides parallel to the axes**;
3. **the top-left corner of both images is initially at the origin** -- N.B. that the top-left corner of the base image is at the origin would suffice and WLOG, as it is equivalent to *all coordinates being relative to the top-left corner of the base image*; but assuming the same for the input image I think is also innocuous since (if I am not missing anything) the initial position of the input image does not affect the result.

Here is an outline:

1. **scale** the blue image so that the distance between $A$ and $B$ in the blue image is equal to distance between $A$ and $B$ in the red image;
2. **rotate** the blue image *around its center* so that the vector (we need direction, parallelism is not enough) $A$ to $B$ in the blue image is equal to the vector $A$ to $B$ in the red image;
3. **translate** the blue image so that points $A$ and $B$ coincide with the corresponding points in the red image;
4. **rotate** the blue image *around its center* by the opposite angle as the one used in 2. (in other words, undo the rotation);
5. extrapolate coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$, which are the transformed coordinates (i.e. along all the transformations above) of the initial top-right and bottom-left corners of the blue image.